# Is this correct ${2\over 3}\cdot{6\over 5}\cdot{10\over 11}\cdots{4n+2\over 4n+2+(-1)^n}\cdots=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}?$

Tags: infinite-product

Given this infinite product

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{2\over 3}\cdot{6\over 5}\cdot{10\over 11}\cdots{4n+2\over 4n+2+(-1)^n}\cdots=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\tag1$$

Where $n\ge0$

**Experimental on the infinite product calculator show $(1)=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$**

**How can we show that?**

Comment: Maybe changing to the following form and compute $\lim ln(y)$ be useful
$$
y=\lim_{n \to \infty}{(1-\frac{1}{3})}\cdot{(1+\frac{1}{5})}\cdot{(1-\frac{1}{11})}\cdots{(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{4n+2+(-1)^n})}
$$

Comment: No, it isn't. I tried it initially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the same spirit as Meet Taraviya's answer, write 
$$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4n+2}{4n+2+(-1)^n}=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(8k+2)(8k+6)}{(8k+3)(8k+5)}$$ Considering the partial product 
$$P_m=\prod_{k=0}^{m}\frac{(8k+2)(8k+6)}{(8k+3)(8k+5)}=\sqrt{\pi }\frac{  \sec \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\, \Gamma \left(2
   m+\frac{5}{2}\right)}{4^{m+1}\,\Gamma \left(m+\frac{11}{8}\right)\, \Gamma
   \left(m+\frac{13}{8}\right)}$$ Now, using Stirling approximation for large values of $m$
$$\log \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(2 m+\frac{5}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(m+\frac{11}{8}\right) \Gamma \left(m+\frac{13}{8}\right)}\right)=2 m \log (2)+\log \left(2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)+\frac{3}{64
   m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$ Truncating to $O\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)$  we then have $$\frac{\Gamma \left(2 m+\frac{5}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(m+\frac{11}{8}\right)
   \Gamma \left(m+\frac{13}{8}\right)}\approx 4^m\times 2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}$$ making $$P_\infty=\frac{\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}=2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4n+2}{4n+2+(-1)^n}&=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{8n+2}{8n+3}\frac{8n+6}{8n+5}\\
&=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{8n+2}{8n+3}\frac{8n+4}{8n+3}\frac{8n+3}{8n+4}\frac{8n+6}{8n+5}\frac{8n+4}{8n+5}\frac{8n+5}{8n+4}\\
&=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{8n+2}{8n+3}\frac{8n+4}{8n+3}\right)\left(\frac{8n+6}{8n+5}\frac{8n+4}{8n+5}\right)\left(\frac{8n+5}{8n+4}\frac{8n+3}{8n+4}\right)\\
&=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{8n+2}{8n+3}\frac{8n+4}{8n+3}\right)\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{8n+6}{8n+5}\frac{8n+4}{8n+5}\right)\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{8n+5}{8n+4}\frac{8n+3}{8n+4}\right)\\
&=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{(8n+3)^2}\right)\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{(8n+4)^2}\right)\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{(8n+5)^2}\right)\\
\end{align}

Now note that using the properies of Gamma function - this kept me busy but fun enough - we have 
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{(8n+q)^2}\right)
&=\frac{(q^2-1)\Gamma\left(\frac{q+8}{8}\right)^2}{q^2\Gamma\left(\frac{q+7}{8}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{q+9}{8}\right)}\\
\end{align}

Therefore your limit becomes:
\begin{align}
l&=\frac{8\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{8}\right)^2}{9\Gamma\left(\frac{10}{8}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{12}{8}\right)}\frac{15\Gamma\left(\frac{12}{8}\right)^2}{16\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{8}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{13}{8}\right)}\frac{24\Gamma\left(\frac{13}{8}\right)^2}{25\Gamma\left(\frac{12}{8}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{14}{8}\right)}\\
&=\frac45\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{8}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{10}{8}\right)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{13}{8}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{14}{8}\right)}\\
&=\frac45\frac{\frac{3}{8}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)}{\frac{2}{8}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{8}\right)}\frac{\frac{5}{8}\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)}{\frac{6}{8}\Gamma\left(\frac{6}{8}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{8}\right)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{6}{8}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\frac{\pi}{\sin\frac38\pi}}{\frac{\pi}{\sin\frac28\pi}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}/2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}/2}=\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}
\end{align}

Comment: excuse me,how could we shift the infinite product to Gamma function?

Answer (score 2):

$$\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{4i+2}{4i+2+(-1)^i}=\Big(\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{4(2k)+2}{4(2k)+2+(-1)^{(2k)}}\Big)\Big(\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{4(2k+1)+2}{4(2k+1)+2+(-1)^{(2k+1)}}\Big)$$
$$=\Big(\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{8k+2}{8k+3}\Big)\Big(\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{8k+6}{8k+5}\Big)$$

See if you can take off from here.

Comment: There is a problem with the first product which tends to $0$ while the second tends to $\infty$ but the idea is good.

Comment: We need not seperate them into different products. But if the limit to the products exist, it might be easier to do so.

Comment: I totally agree with you and I gave you credit in my answer.